# PHP: how to save result of recursive function in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

I have changed version of this recursive function...
http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/databases/mysql/handling-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-and-php.html

What I need is a way to save the returned value of this function in an array so that I can reverse the order of array elements. The function works well for me, but I need a way to save values. Here is the code...

```
function display_children($category_id, $level) {
  global $database;
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id_roditelja='$category_id'") or die(mysql_error());
  $niz = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo str_repeat('  ', $level) . $row['naziv'] . "<br/>";
    array_push($niz, display_children($row['parent_id'], $level + 1));
//this is one way I tried, and I get $niz with exact number of elements but each is null
//in this $niz array I need to store values of recursion
    var_dump($niz);
  }
}
```

Comment: chould you dump $niz outside the while, your null problem is probably because of the second parameter given to array_push. Your recursive function does not return any value to be send to array_push, I mean you have lots of operation, but no value at the end

Comment: @som: can you explain why this is not a recursive function ? It calls itself ? Thug: you forgot return $niz; after your while

Comment: Sorry I don't see properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function display_children/* <- this must be the same */($category_id, $level) {
  global $database;
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id_roditelja='$category_id'") or     die(mysql_error());
  $niz = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $niz[] = str_repeat('  ', $level) . $row['naziv'] . "<br/>"; // we need to save this
    $niz = array_merge($niz, /* as this -> */display_children($row['parent_id'], $level + 1)); // array_merge doesn't take a reference so we need to store its result in $niz
  }
  return $niz;
}
```

if you want a tree like structure use array_push instead of array_merge.
As noone seems to notice: His function can't return anything without a return statement !

Comment: As maybe we have already noticed that, but in comments, because one more row, does not deserve a whole answer :)

Comment: Same result as my way...null again. My function returns names of products, as it should, but i need it saved in array, because order of elements in not the right.

Comment: @Thug your function (how you posted it) may display something but it won't return anything because it lacks a return statement ! Can you post how you call your function and an example output ?

Comment: This is example od output Zaštita za zube
Borilački aksesoari
Borilački sportovi
Sportska oprema
array
  0 => null
array
  0 => null
array
  0 => null
array
  0 => null

Comment: i call function like display_chield(58,4);

Comment: @Thug please take a look at my edits. Are they usefull? Try var_dump(display_children(58,4)); it should display the array with your values from the database.

Comment: @Christoph i try it like u said, and i got same result. That vardump is from your code. :)

Comment: @Thug did you try with my changes ? I can't imagine that it outputs null somewhere. Moreover it shouldn't var_dump() more then once.

Comment: @Christoph yes, i tried your code, copied all change name of function and display it, with same result.

Comment: @Thug It works correctly for me: http://codepad.org/MVtqhuYF (changed the mysql_query with a static array because i don't have your database)

Comment: I get this message Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in  on line 107. And line 107 is $niz = array_merge($niz, display_children($row['parent_id'], $level + 1)); // array_merge doesn't take a reference so we need to store its result in $niz

Comment: @Thug are you renaming my function and forget to rename the call inside? (see comments in answer)

Comment: I tried something, and that's happend :) my bad :) but my function still not working :( i'll go crazy...it must be something stupid..

Comment: I did it :) dont know what, but i did it :) Thank you @Christoph for help!

Comment: @Thug good to know hopefully next time it will work faster fast you ;)